# I have a textview, but I need data according to lines. First 4 lines, 3 lines etc

Tags: android

I have a text from a QR Code. 
Text Pattern is Like this and this whole text reside in a textview :

abc Ahtasham is there
def not there
110 yes not
120 etc etc etc

TEXTFEILD “abc” (required)
FREE TEXTFIELD for address

TEXTFIELD “def” (required)
FREE TEXTFIELD for contact person

I need to put first four lines in a textview, other 2 lines in other textview and other 2 lines in another textview.
I want to know how I can get the data on line basis. Can any one help. Thankyou.

Comment: Do you mean how to split the whole text into lines?

Comment: I have a textview in which the whole text is written, I need to get the text on line basis, let say text from line 1 to 2 and then 2 to 4

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
private String getLines(String txt, int aFrom, int aTo) {
    // create an array with all lines 
    String[] lines = txt.split("\\r?\\n");  
    String result = "";
    for (int i = aFrom; i <= aTo; i++) 
        result += lines[i] + "\n";
    return result;
}
```

Use like this

```
textV2.setText(getLines(textV1.getText(), 0, 3)); // get first 4 lines
textV3.setText(getLines(textV1.getText(), 4, 5)); // get next 2 lines  
// and so on..
```